# Subconsulta com Sum SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server

Boa tarde galera, blz ?
Estou tendo problemas em uma consulta utilizando SUM onde preciso retornar as colunas e a somatória de uma outra determinada coluna.
Para tentar resolver o problema adicionei uma subquery em minha seção de select, consigo o retorno da consulta, porém não está correto, quando igualo meus IDLANs a consulta me retorna o valor da linha, quando igualo apenas a filial ela retorna a somatória da tabela inteira.

Alguém poderia me dar uma Luz ?

Obrigado !

```
SELECT 
 FLAN.DATABAIXA                                                                              AS [RECEBIMENTO],
 FLAN.DATAEMISSAO,
 FCFO.NOMEFANTASIA,
 FCFO.CGCCFO                                                                                 AS [CREDOR],
 FLAN.CODCCUSTO                                                                              AS [CENTRO_CUSTO],
 G.NOME                                                                                      AS [NOME CC],
 CASE 
     WHEN CAST (FLAN.STATUSLAN AS VARCHAR) = 1 THEN 'T'
     WHEN CAST (FLAN.STATUSLAN AS VARCHAR) = 4 THEN 'P'
     ELSE CAST (FLAN.STATUSLAN AS VARCHAR)
 END                                                                                         AS [SITUACAO],
 CONCAT(FLAN.CODTDO,' / ',FLAN.NUMERODOCUMENTO)                                              AS [DOC / Nº DOC],
 FLAN.IDLAN                                                                                  AS [LANÇAMENTO],
 CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), FLAN.VALORORIGINAL)                                                 AS [VALOR],
 FLANBAIXA.VALORORIGINAL                                                                     AS [VALOR BAIXA],
 ISNULL(FLANBAIXA.VALORMULTA,0) + ISNULL(FLANBAIXA.VALORJUROS,0)                             AS [ACRESCIMO],
 ISNULL(FLANBAIXA.VALORDESCONTO,0)                                                           AS [DESCONTO],
 FLAN.VALORBAIXADO                                                                           AS [VALOR RECEBIDO],
 (SELECT SUM(FL.VALORORIGINAL) FROM FLAN FL WHERE FL.CODCOLIGADA = FLAN.CODCOLIGADA
 AND FL.IDLAN = FLAN.IDLAN)                                                                  AS [TOTAL]
 
FROM   
 FLAN (NOLOCK)
 INNER JOIN FCFO (NOLOCK) 
     ON FLAN.CODCOLCFO = FCFO.CODCOLIGADA 
     AND FLAN.CODCFO = FCFO.CODCFO
 LEFT JOIN FLANRATCCU R (NOLOCK) 
     ON R.CODCOLIGADA = FLAN.CODCOLIGADA 
     AND R.IDLAN = FLAN.IDLAN
 LEFT JOIN TTBORCAMENTO H (NOLOCK) 
     ON R.CODCOLNATFINANCEIRA = H.CODCOLIGADA 
     AND R.CODNATFINANCEIRA = H.CODTBORCAMENTO
 LEFT JOIN GCCUSTO G (NOLOCK)
     ON FLAN.CODCOLIGADA = G.CODCOLIGADA 
     AND FLAN.CODCCUSTO = G.CODCCUSTO
 INNER JOIN FTDO (NOLOCK)
     ON FLAN.CODCOLIGADA = FTDO.CODCOLIGADA 
     AND FLAN.CODTDO = FTDO.CODTDO
 INNER JOIN FLANBAIXA (NOLOCK)
     ON FLAN.CODCOLIGADA = FLANBAIXA.CODCOLIGADA
     AND FLAN.IDLAN = FLANBAIXA.IDLAN

WHERE 
 FLAN.IDLAN IN (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimente utilizar a função *Sum* com a clausula *Over* e o argumento *Partition* no lugar da subquery:

```
SUM(FLAN.VALORORIGINAL) OVER(PARTITION BY FLAN.CODCOLIGADA)
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16